# Rspec: block runs multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a simple test in rspec as follows:

```
RSpec.describe "api_request", type: :request do
   context "when a certain case is true" do
      it "returns true" do
        test_user = create(:user)
        puts "hello world"
        # jsonapi_get "/my_api_url"
        # expect([1,23]).to eq([1,22])
      end
   end
end
```

While working on this block, I noticed that the block is being executed multiple times. To ascertain this, I inserted the `puts` statement, and went on commenting line by line to check which line exactly is causing the reruns.

After multiple trials it turns out that un-commenting the expect statement causes "hello world" to be displayed 3 times, meaning the block keeps getting re-executed.

I tried taking this block out of context, and inserting it in different describe blocks all with the same result. My question is, how can I work around this weird behavior of expect?

Comment: nope, this `expect` line can't affect anything and it most certainly does not re-run the line before it (or the block it's in) three times. Perhaps you went too far in trying to simplify your code for the question.

Comment: This is the exact same test I used to ascertain that the expect causes hello_world to be displayed 3 times. Running with the line, displays 3 times. Commenting the line displays hello world once

Comment: @dbugger noo not overridden in the entire code base

Comment: "This is the exact same test I used" - I trust that this is what you saw, but this is impossible. There's something else (not shown here) that might be causing this behaviour. At this point, I'd like to see a runnable example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: And this only happens in this test block?

Comment: @dbugger it might be a setting in their rspec config that reruns failed specs a few times (a poor man's way of handling flaky specs)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I don't think RSpec actually has that feature built in. It can be done though [rspec-rerun](https://github.com/dblock/rspec-rerun) or other test runners / CI tools.

Comment: @max I know I used something like this a few jobs ago. Don't remember if it was built-in or not. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: actually based on ur guess @max found a gem called rspec-retry installed in our code base. Will check if this is configured

Comment: Also makes sense because the multiple statements are only returned on a failing test. Tried expect([1,23]).to eq([1,23]) and the statement is only displayed once. So probably that @max

Comment: That sounds like the culprit right there.